# ANTLR 4: How to properly handle minus unary operator

Tags: antlr4

I'm creating a custom, simple programming language that should only allow printing basic math operations.

Here's my current grammar:

```
grammar mar ;


start
  : expression+ EOF
  ;


expression
  : PRINT context SEMI               # PrintExpr
  ;

context : factor term
  ;

term
  : MUL factor term                  # Mul
  | DIV factor term                  # Div
  | ADD factor term                  # Add
  | SUB factor term                  # Sub
  |                                  # Empty
  ;

factor
  : LPAREN context RPAREN            # Paren
  | SUB factor                       # Neg
  | DOUBLE                           # DOUBLE
  ;


DOUBLE : [0-9]+('.'[0-9]+)? ;

PRINT  : 'print ' ;
SEMI   : ';' ;
ADD    : '+' ;
SUB    : '-' ;
MUL    : '*' ;
DIV    : '/' ;
LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;


WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Everything is working as intended, except for the fact that this grammar allows inputting two minus (-) signs in a row due to the recursion on the factor rule (`SUB factor`).

How can I achieve a grammar that would not allow inputs like `print 5--3;` or `print --3;`?

I already tried refactoring the `factor` rule to

```
factor
  : LPAREN context RPAREN                          # Paren
  | DOUBLE                                         # DOUBLE
  | {input.LT(1).getText() == '-'}? '-' DOUBLE     # Neg
  ;
```

but it did not work for other valid inputs as it did before this refactoring.

Comment: But double minus is valid input in expressions, like `a + b - -c`. Why do you want to get rid of that?

Comment: @MikeLischke that's indeed valid, but `a+b--c` shouldn't. Basically, two unary minus shouldn't appear next to each other, and that's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I just see you try to implement reverse polish notation in your expressions (I don't know the Mathlab syntax). In this situation it's indeed invalid to have two minuses in a row without a second parameter after the second minus. But that would be a syntax error your parser should report to you, because it cannot finish the `term` rule then.

Comment: I believe even `+ a b - - -c d e` is valid syntax (evaluated as: `a + (b - (((-c) - d) - e))`, if I'm not totally wrong. My RPN knowledge is a bit rusty.

Comment: `+ a b - - -c d e` doesn't seem to be valid syntax for this grammar, because (1) unary plus is not allowed and (2) constants must have an operator between them

Comment: @MikeLischke, is making the Parser handle this a possible solution? If so, is it the only solution? I would prefer to achieve a solution by simply modifying the grammar, if possible.

Comment: Simply add a lexer rule: `MINUSMINUS: '--';`. First, remember that Antlr lexers will chose the rule that matches the longest string regardless of the order of the lexer rules. And, if there are two lexer rules that match the same string, the first one wins. Second, simply don't reference the MINUSMINUS token in your parser grammar rules. The parser will raise an SyntaxError() at that token.

Comment: @kaby76 that works for me, thanks for the explanation and solution! Feel free to post your comment as an answer to this question so other people with the same problem can see it quicker.